# $watch on angular.element(document).height() reports incorrect values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which performs calculations based on document height, each time document height is changed I have to redo my calculations again.

In order to do recalculate on document height change, I set `$watch` over document

```
        scope.$watch(function() {
            return angular.element(document).height();
        }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
            scope.height = newVal;
            console.log('height: ', newVal);
        });
```

Initially, `angular.element(document).height()` reports height of `664px`(higher). Expanding (by clicking) on one of divs, height is reported as `298px`(lower), now play with it by expanding/collapsing and you'll see value always changes to previous one.
If I open the console and `scope.$apply()`, the value is correctly updated, but it's not a solution, you cant run `scope.$apply()` inside `$watch`, you'll get infinite digest loop.

Here is the issue demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/vladimir_ze/pmxsvu9g/2/

What can be done so I always get always currect document height?